# Properly manage nav bar and tab bar

Tags: swift, navbar, tabbar

The figure shows my storyboard, with segues as directed.

[image: storyboard]

In the tabBar's landing viewcontroller (i.e. I), both tabBar and navBar are visible which is desired. However, if a segue is performed (from I) to go to another viewcontroller (here, II), I want only the navBar. I am able to hide the tabBar by using

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Next, I am able to achieve the desired result by adding navigation controller at the beginning as shown below.

[image]

This configuration will add a navbar to the viewcontrollers ahead (like splash screen) so I will have to hide the navbar in those viewcontrollers.

Is there other method that does not require to hide the bar(s) and achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You seem to have solved your own problem — in at least two different ways! So what's the question?

Comment: I am not certain that the solutions i have mentioned are proper ways. So I wanted to know how can i align nav bar controller and tab bar controller to obtain the effect I have mentioned, without the need of writing the code to hide the bar.

Comment: As you've been told, there is a `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property. But the premise of your question is curious. Code is not _bad_ in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with your first approach. Tab bar controller have default property to hide bottom bar. See below sample code.

```
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;  // This property needs to be set before pushing viewController to the navigationController's stack. 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

This will hide your tab bar while pushing to any child controllers.

EDIT

You can also set hidesBottomBarwhenpushed from storyboard for your tabbar controller so you don’t have to write down any code.

Comment: I tried using the storyboard option. Once i hid the tab bar in a viewcontroller, it remained hidden for all other viewcontrollers that followed. This is what I needed for now.